# ¿Como validar que el textarea no este vacío en php y no inserte datos?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, mysqli, php7

Estoy agregando una opción de comentarios en un apartado de la página que estoy tratando de crear, pero me he encontrado un problema... Me valida "bien" el hecho de que no hay comentario en el textarea, pero en aun así envía el comentario vacío a la bd.

```
if(isset($enviar) && isset($comentario)){

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO resumen_trabajo_realizado (comentario) VALUES ('$comentario')");
alert("Se ha realizado el comentario",1,'clientes');

}if(empty($comentario) && isset($enviar)){

alert("No",0,'resumen_trabajo_realizado');

}
```

Como dije valida que mi text area esta vacía, pero igual mente manda el comentario vacío a la bd. Una de las soluciones que había encontrado también es poner en la etiqueta del textarea, al final REQUIRED el problema es que tu simplemente puedes dejar de lado esto haciendo un simple espacio y manda el espacio en blanco a la bd.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá una foto de que me sale el despectivo error cuando trato de mandar  un comentario vacío:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y otra foto de que manda el texto a la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en que en tu `if` estas validando que tus variables existan sin importar si están vacías o no, y debido a que el elemento existe se esta ejecutando tu query lo ideal sería que hagas la validación de que existe y que a su ves no este vació algo así `if (isset($comentario) && !empty($comentario)` quedaría algo así tu código

```
if(isset($enviar) && isset($comentario) && (!empty($comentario))){

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO resumen_trabajo_realizado (comentario) VALUES ('$comentario')");
alert("Se ha realizado el comentario",1,'clientes');

} else if (isset($enviar)) {

  alert("No",0,'resumen_trabajo_realizado');

}
```

Comment: Esto me sirvió perfecto! Pero me salta un nuevo problema, que es que, cuando apenas abres la ventana por así decirle de comentarios, me sale de una el error del "No" (aclaro, simplemente no le doy okey, voy y trato de mandar un comentario vacío y ahora si NO se inserta a la bd, luego mando un comentario con lo que sea "xyz" y ahí si inserta) Pero valida antes de tan si quiera darle a enviar.

Comment: en tu `else` añade un `if` que valide si existe `$enviar` seria algo así `else if (isset($enviar)) { alert("No",0,'resumen_trabajo_realizado'); }`

Comment: acabo de actualizar mi respuesta para que veas mas o menos como quedaría

Comment: Acabo de aplicar el código como me dijiste, funciono a la perfección, muchas gracias!

Comment: Aunque de casualidad, pregunta fuera del tema ya... Como evitar que si vengo y le doy espacio tipo "      " Me evite la inserción de eso en la bd?

Comment: para evitar que agreguen espacios en blanco como texto puedes utilizar `trim()` en tu validación de la siguiente manera `if (!empty(trim($comentarios)))` de esta manera antes de hacer la validación de si esta vació o no, esta realizando un corte de los espacios vacíos

Comment: perfecto! Eso soluciono todos los problemas, muchas gracias...